# agora.io flutter Access denied finding property "net.dns1"

Tags: flutter, agora.io

```
    // Get microphone permission
    await PermissionHandler().requestPermissions(
      [PermissionGroup.microphone],
    );

    var engine = await RtcEngine.create(APP_ID);
    engine.enableAudio();

    // Define event handler
    engine.setEventHandler(RtcEngineEventHandler(
        joinChannelSuccess: (String channel, int uid, int elapsed) {
          print('joinChannelSuccess ${channel} ${uid}');
          setState(() {
            _joined = true;
          });
        }, userJoined: (int uid, int elapsed) {
      print('userJoined ${uid}');
      setState(() {
        _remoteUid = uid;
      });
    }, userOffline: (int uid, UserOfflineReason reason) {
      print('userOffline ${uid}');
      setState(() {
        _remoteUid = null;
      });
    }));
    // Join channel 123
    await engine.joinChannel(Token, '123', null, 0);
```

i am tring to build audio calling app using agora.io but i keep getting this error saying "Access denied finding property "net.dns1" "

Comment: I searched about this error a lot but everything would work with it too!

Comment: You should not have any issue with this error.